# How do I control the size of an (open) HTML widget for iBooks Author?

Tags: html, widget, ibooks

I've looked and experimented without fully understanding this. I'm missing something. There are at least 4 places you specify the size of your widget for iBooks author:

- In your plist
- In your HTML
- In the inspector for the widget in iBooks author itself (I thought this was just for the unopened widget, but sometimes the open widget appears to stay this size)
- As the size of `Default.png`

In addition, you can set whether the widget displays full screen or not. This latter does not seem to zoom the widget to full screen, just blanks out the rest. And behavior seems different on the computer versus on an iPad, say.

So: how DO you set the size?

I'd be grateful for an authoritative answer, or a pointer to where this is explained. Thanks!